# VBE menu bar malfunction

Tags: vba

When I open VBA Editor from any office app, the menu and toolbar have shrunk, and they are totally non responsive. So are the Window buttons at the top right. The main windows (immediate, code, etc.) all work fine, but nothing at the top works. I don't even know what to type into Google to search for the problem....thoughts?

I've attached an image to try and help explain the problem:
[image]

Comment: What happens when you type within the code window - does your cursor "jump" as you move from the small area within the "shrunken" zone into the part of the code window that is in the "normal size" zone?  Do the characters you type appear to be the same font size in both of the "zones".  Have you tried clicking the spots where the menu items would be if the menu bar was not shrunken?  Have you tried using the keyboard, e.g. Alt-V, or have you just tried the mouse?.

Comment: Keyboard commands work. Clicking anywhere in the dead area actually clicks on whatever screen/app is open behind it; there is no way to interact directly with the dead area. The cursor does not jump.

Comment: Also, exact same problem on my QGIS app. I even uninstalled that one and reinstalled a different version, and the menu/toolbar is still missing. So far, it's only those two apps (QGIS and VBE). The main MS Office apps all seem to work fine, as do my browser tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was related to having an extended desktop. Eventually noticed the following:

- When I took the active window off of "maximized" the dead area went
  away.
- The dead area didn't happen if I moved the active window to    the
  second monitor

Changing the display settings to monitor 1 only, then changing it back to extended desktop seems to have solved the problem.